# Undefined index 'submit' when sending email through php

Tags: php, html, email

I have created a 'contact me' form and i am trying to send an email to a particular email address. However i am not good with server-end programming and i am getting an undefined index/ variable error which i can not seem to resolve. Can you please point out the fault.

Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: submit in C:\xampp\htdocs\unnamed\upload.php on line 4

**HTML Code**

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" style="height:100%">

            <input name="articleTitle" value="Title" maxlength="50" 
            id="articleTitle">

            <textarea name="article-body">
                Compose your article...
            </textarea>

        <script>
            CKEDITOR.inline( 'article-body' );
        </script>

    <br>
            <input name="senderName" type="text" value="Name" maxlength="50" 
            id="name" class="textBox">

            <input name="senderEmail" value="Email address" maxlength="50" 
            id="email" class="textBox">

            <input name="abtyou" value="About Yourself" maxlength="150" 
            id="abtyou" class="textBox">

            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button">

</form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
    <?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {
    $recipient="zain.farid@live.com";
    $subject="New Guest Post";
    $sender=$_POST["senderName"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["senderEmail"];
    $senderAbout=$_POST["abtyou"];
    $message=$_POST["article-body"];
    $title=$_POST["articleTitle"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nAbout Sender: $senderAbout\nTitle: $title\n\n$message";

    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your post has been submitted.</p>";
}

?>
```

Thank You.

Comment: *"undefined index/ variable error"* - Why don't you show us the "real" error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have updated the question with the error.

Comment: Ok, well see Rizier's answer below. That's what you should use, and not `if($_POST["submit"])`.

Comment: So, success or failure?

Comment: @Fred-ii- the error is gone but mail function is not working.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: And replace `mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>");` with `if(mail($recipient, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $sender <$senderEmail>")){ echo "Success";} else{ echo "Error"; }` and use error reporting as I stated above. Plus, if you're using this on a free host, chances are that they do not offer `mail()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- okaay let me try

Comment: @Fred-ii- no error reported. Success is echoed but still no email in my inbox.

Comment: Check your spam then. Your code worked for me. If it persists, contact your host. Or, are you running this from your own computer instead of a hosted service? If from your own machine, check your configurations.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am testing it by running on a remote server like on localhost/ xampp.

Comment: You will need to go over your configuration files in regards to mail / SMTP and the documentation on it. I know nothing about xampp but can say that it's most likely a configuration problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check in the if statement if it is set with: `isset()`

Like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
```

Comment: Thank you. 
i used `isset` and the error is not there anymore. However it is not sending the mail. Can you please point out an error?